# Set data from fetching by list in peoplepicker component

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, react

```
import {
    PeoplePicker,
    PrincipalType,
  } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/PeoplePicker";
  import * as React from "react";
//People Picker Component
  const PeoplepickerForm = ({
    context,
    onChange,
    limit,
    groupName,
    peoplePickerData
  }:any) => {
    return(<>
      <PeoplePicker
                          context={context}
                          placeholder="Enter Name or EmailID"
                          defaultSelectedUsers={peoplePickerData}
                          personSelectionLimit={limit}
                          showtooltip={false}
                          required={true}
                          groupName={groupName}
                          disabled={false}
                          showHiddenInUI={false}
                          ensureUser={true}
                          principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
                          resolveDelay={1000}
                          onChange={onChange}
                        />
    </>)
  }

  export default PeoplepickerForm;
```

this was my peoplepicker component and

```
 const getData = async(id:number) => {
    let url = `${props.webURL}/_api/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$select=ReportingManagerId,ReportingManager/Title,&$expand=ReportingManager,&$filter=ID eq ${id}&$orderby=ID desc`
       
 const  data = await ListOperations.getPageList(props.context,url)
        console.log(data)
        if(data.value.length > 0){
          let temp : any[] = []
          let url = props.webURL.split("/")
          data.value.map(async(d:any)=> {
            

            setReportingManager([{title : d.ReportingManager.Title, id : d.ReportingManagerId}])

       
       // setReportingManager(d.ReportingManagerId)
         await  _getPeoplePickerItems([d.ReportingManagerId])
        
    


          })
         
        }
  }
const _getPeoplePickerItems = (items: any[]) => {
  let getSelectedUsers = "";
  for (let item in items) {
    getSelectedUsers = items[item].id;
  }
```

and from this function I'm getting data with `reportermangerid` and this reporter manager I want to set in peoplepicker component so how can I do it?